# Taking the partial derivative of an integral

Tags: integration, partial-derivative

Can I simply take the integral of this function with respect to $t$ by bringing the differential operator under the summation?

$$u(x,t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\phi(\zeta)}{t^{1/2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\zeta)^2}{4t}\right)d\zeta$$

I don't think it requires an application of Leibniz.

Comment: That is what Leibniz rule is for.  Can you explain why you don't think you would need it?

Comment: Well we're not taking the derivative with respect to the same variable as we are integrating for, perhaps I'm misunderstanding but I don't think u depends of $\zeta$?

Comment: Leibniz's rule says you can do the following $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int f(x,t)dx = \int \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(x,t)dx$.  That seems to me what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd consider using Leibniz's rule to solve your problem.  A simplification of it says you can do the following $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int f(\zeta,t)d\zeta = \int \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(\zeta,t)d\zeta$.  That seems to me what you want to do.  You can read about it at [Leibniz Integral Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Comment: but what I would be saying is that  $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int f(x,\zeta,t)d\zeta = \int \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(x,\zeta,t)d\zeta$ and so i'm not sure if it still applies

Comment: It definitely still applies, $x$ is a constant with respect to the integration and derivative, so you might as well just think of it as a number instead of a variable.